How to extract data using LeetCode GraphQL query
I just want to know that how to print all the JSON using the GraphQL API?
Like I want to extract all the data of LeetCode user profiles for my project, but I don't know how to write the query to extract all the data of a profile.
I want to extract some specific details from a user's LeetCode profile but before that I want to print all the JSON data so that I can write specific query to extract specific information.
Is there any way to print all the data or where I can learn to what to write in the query to extract the specific information form the user's profile.
My primary coding language is python.

So graphql is kind of designed on the notion that a json data payload is hierarchical and that one should not return parts of the hierarchy that have no been requested. So, at a high level, if you want the "full json payload" you have to request that and to do so, you would have to know the schema.

I think @JonSG explained enough about graphql, so I just gave you a head start on how to code to get your desired output from JSON using the Graphql API.
Note: I added 10 pages in range just for the demo, leetcode has 22341 page of user list in the global ranking.
Sample Code:
import requests
from string import Template

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:131.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/131.0",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
url = 'https://leetcode.com/graphql'
for i in range(1,10):
    val = 'query globalRanking {\n  globalRanking(page: $page) {\n    totalUsers\n    userPerPage\n    myRank {\n      ranking\n      currentGlobalRanking\n      currentRating\n      dataRegion\n      user {\n        nameColor\n        activeBadge {\n          displayName\n          icon\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    rankingNodes {\n      ranking\n      currentRating\n      currentGlobalRanking\n      dataRegion\n      user {\n        username\n        nameColor\n        activeBadge {\n          displayName\n          icon\n          __typename\n        }\n        profile {\n          userSlug\n          userAvatar\n          countryCode\n          countryName\n          realName\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n'
    s = Template(val)
    replace_page = s.substitute(page=i)
    data = {
    "operationName": "globalRanking",
    "variables": {},
    "query": f"{replace_page}"
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=data)
    for i in response.json()['data']['globalRanking']['rankingNodes']:
        data = [f"user_name: {i['user']['username']}", f"user_avatar: {i['user']['profile']['userAvatar']}", f"country: {i['user']['profile']['countryName']}", f"name: {i['user']['profile']['realName']}"]
        print(data)

Sample Output:
['user_name: neal_wu', 'user_avatar: https://assets.leetcode.com/users/neal_wu/avatar_1574529913.png', 'country: United States', 'name: Neal Wu']
['user_name: Carefreejs', 'user_avatar: https://aliyun-lc-upload.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/aliyun-lc-upload/users/endlesscheng/avatar_1690721039.png', 'country: ', 'name: 灵茶山艾府']
['user_name: numb3r5', 'user_avatar: https://assets.leetcode.com/users/default_avatar.jpg', 'country: Australia', 'name: Joshua Chen']
['user_name: liming-v', 'user_avatar: https://aliyun-lc-upload.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/aliyun-lc-upload/users/heltion/avatar_1587213058.png', 'country: 中国', 'name: 何逊']
['user_name: ahmed007boss', 'user_avatar: https://aliyun-lc-upload.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/aliyun-lc-upload/users/yawn_sean/avatar_1654149069.png', 'country: 中国', 'name: 小羊肖恩']
['user_name: hankray', 'user_avatar: https://aliyun-lc-upload.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/aliyun-lc-upload/users/sserxhs/avatar_1622949152.png', 'country: 中国', 'name: SSerxhs']
['user_name: dnialh', 'user_avatar: https://assets.leetcode.com/users/avatars/avatar_1655848184.png', 'country: None', 'name: ']
['user_name: fjzzq2002', 'user_avatar: https://assets.leetcode.com/users/default_avatar.jpg', 'country: None', 'name: ']
['user_name: pandaforever', 'user_avatar: https://assets.leetcode.com/users/default_avatar.jpg', 'country: None', 'name: ']
['user_name: zhoupeiyun', 'user_avatar: https://aliyun-lc-upload.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/aliyun-lc-upload/users/johnkram/avatar_1593402741.png', 'country: 中国', 'name: 汪乐平']
['user_name: getnaukri', 'user_avatar: https://aliyun-lc-upload.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/aliyun-lc-upload/users/py-is-best-lang/avatar_1692179558.png', 'country: ', 'name: PyIsBestLang']
['user_name: jonathanirvings', 'user_avatar: https://assets.leetcode.com/users/default_avatar.jpg', 'country: Singapore', 'name: Jonathan Irvin Gunawan']
['user_name: xiaowuc1', 'user_avatar: https://assets.leetcode.com/users/default_avatar.jpg', 'country: United States', 'name: xiaowuc1']
['user_name: PurpleCrayon', 'user_avatar: https://assets.leetcode.com/users/rohingarg123/avatar_1584377597.png', 'country: None', 'name: Rohin Garg']

All the queries will be used as a request body to extract specific user data:
Public profile: {"query":"\n    query userPublicProfile($username: String!) {\n  matchedUser(username: $username) {\n    contestBadge {\n      name\n      expired\n      hoverText\n      icon\n    }\n    username\n    githubUrl\n    twitterUrl\n    linkedinUrl\n    profile {\n      ranking\n      userAvatar\n      realName\n      aboutMe\n      school\n      websites\n      countryName\n      company\n      jobTitle\n      skillTags\n      postViewCount\n      postViewCountDiff\n      reputation\n      reputationDiff\n      solutionCount\n      solutionCountDiff\n      categoryDiscussCount\n      categoryDiscussCountDiff\n    }\n  }\n}\n    ","variables":{"username":"TARGET USERNAME IS HERE"},"operationName":"userPublicProfile"}    
Language Stats: {"query":"\n    query languageStats($username: String!) {\n  matchedUser(username: $username) {\n    languageProblemCount {\n      languageName\n      problemsSolved\n    }\n  }\n}\n    ","variables":{"username":"TARGET USERNAME IS HERE"},"operationName":"languageStats"}    
Skills set: {"query":"\n    query skillStats($username: String!) {\n  matchedUser(username: $username) {\n    tagProblemCounts {\n      advanced {\n        tagName\n        tagSlug\n        problemsSolved\n      }\n      intermediate {\n        tagName\n        tagSlug\n        problemsSolved\n      }\n      fundamental {\n        tagName\n        tagSlug\n        problemsSolved\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n    ","variables":{"username":"TARGET USERNAME IS HERE"},"operationName":"skillStats"}    
User Contest Ranking: {"query":"\n    query userContestRankingInfo($username: String!) {\n  userContestRanking(username: $username) {\n    attendedContestsCount\n    rating\n    globalRanking\n    totalParticipants\n    topPercentage\n    badge {\n      name\n    }\n  }\n  userContestRankingHistory(username: $username) {\n    attended\n    trendDirection\n    problemsSolved\n    totalProblems\n    finishTimeInSeconds\n    rating\n    ranking\n    contest {\n      title\n      startTime\n    }\n  }\n}\n    ","variables":{"username":"TARGET USERNAME IS HERE"},"operationName":"userContestRankingInfo"}    
User question progress V2: {"query":"\n    query userProfileUserQuestionProgressV2($userSlug: String!) {\n  userProfileUserQuestionProgressV2(userSlug: $userSlug) {\n    numAcceptedQuestions {\n      count\n      difficulty\n    }\n    numFailedQuestions {\n      count\n      difficulty\n    }\n    numUntouchedQuestions {\n      count\n      difficulty\n    }\n    userSessionBeatsPercentage {\n      difficulty\n      percentage\n    }\n  }\n}\n    ","variables":{"userSlug":"TARGET USERNAME IS HERE"},"operationName":"userProfileUserQuestionProgressV2"
User question progress V1: {"query":"\n    query userSessionProgress($username: String!) {\n  allQuestionsCount {\n    difficulty\n    count\n  }\n  matchedUser(username: $username) {\n    submitStats {\n      acSubmissionNum {\n        difficulty\n        count\n        submissions\n      }\n      totalSubmissionNum {\n        difficulty\n        count\n        submissions\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n    ","variables":{"username":"TARGET USERNAME IS HERE"},"operationName":"userSessionProgress"}    
User Badge: {"query":"\n    query userBadges($username: String!) {\n  matchedUser(username: $username) {\n    badges {\n      id\n      name\n      shortName\n      displayName\n      icon\n      hoverText\n      medal {\n        slug\n        config {\n          iconGif\n          iconGifBackground\n        }\n      }\n      creationDate\n      category\n    }\n    upcomingBadges {\n      name\n      icon\n      progress\n    }\n  }\n}\n    ","variables":{"username":"TARGET USERNAME IS HERE"},"operationName":"userBadges"}    
User profile calendar: {"query":"\n    query userProfileCalendar($username: String!, $year: Int) {\n  matchedUser(username: $username) {\n    userCalendar(year: $year) {\n      activeYears\n      streak\n      totalActiveDays\n      dccBadges {\n        timestamp\n        badge {\n          name\n          icon\n        }\n      }\n      submissionCalendar\n    }\n  }\n}\n    ","variables":{"username":"TARGET USERNAME IS HERE"},"operationName":"userProfileCalendar"}    
User recent submission: {"query":"\n    query recentAcSubmissions($username: String!, $limit: Int!) {\n  recentAcSubmissionList(username: $username, limit: $limit) {\n    id\n    title\n    titleSlug\n    timestamp\n  }\n}\n    ","variables":{"username":"TARGET USERNAME IS HERE","limit":15},"operationName":"recentAcSubmissions"}

let me know if this is what you want!

All these queries are perfect, @x1337Loser I want to know how to write these queries in the context of LeetCode's GraphQL.

Should i drop the demo code using those queries? Because i already gave you a sample usage of queries, that's why i think i should drop the full version of code, let me know

I want to know how to write these queries. Like how will I know first there will be userPublicProfile then matchedUser then contestBadge etc.

It’s easy you should use your firefox/chrome network tab to find all the request that made by your target app, then click one by one and check post body to extract the graph queries  --> now you learned how to know which queries does what! i used burp proxy tools to get all of these queries similar to chrome/firefox network tab!

Is there any way to improve my question? I'm receiving the message 'You can’t post new questions right now' while trying to ask another question and I think I can remove this restriction by improving the quality of my existing questions

Is there any way to improve my question? I'm receiving the message 'You can’t post new questions right now' while trying to ask another question and I think I can remove this restriction by improving the quality of my existing questions
